# Is this property on ODE correct?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

Let $\Omega=]a,b[\times\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}^n$ continuous and locally Lipschitz for the second variable.Let $y:]c,d[\to \mathbb{R}^n$ a maximal solution for the Cauchy's problem ($y'(t)=f(t,y(t))$ and $y(t_0)=y_0$). If $d<b$ then $\| y(t) \| \to +\infty$ when $t\to d$. Same if $a<c$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you think it's true? Why? What's the source of this proposition? What have you tried to prove it / find an counterexample?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I tried with $y'(t)=y^2 (t)$ on $]-\infty,0[$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At any point in $(t_0,x_0) \in (a,b) \times \mathbb{R}^n$ there is a unique local solution passing through $(t_0,x_0)$.

Suppose $y$ is a maximal solution bounded by some $K$ on $[t_0,d)$. Since $f$ is bounded on the compact set
$[t_0,d] \times \overline{B}(0,K)$, we see that $y$ is Lipschitz and hence
$y_1 = \lim_{t \uparrow d} y(t) $ exists and we see that 
$\lim_{t \uparrow d} \dot{y}(t) = f(d,y_1)$. In particular, $y$ satisfies the
differential equation on $[t_0,d]$.

Since a local solution $\eta$ passing through $(d,y_1)$
exists, we have $\eta(t) = y(t)$ for $t$ in $(d-\delta,d)$ with some $\delta>0$,
and since $\eta$ is defined on an open interval containing $d$ we see that the
solution can be extended, which contradicts maximality.

The above only shows that $\limsup_{t \uparrow d} \|y(t)\| = \infty$.

Choose some $R>0$ then let $L$ be a bound for $f$ on $[t_0,d] \times \overline{B}(0,2R)$. Then note that if $t,t+\delta \in [t_0,d)$ and $y(t) \in \overline{B}(0,R)$ (note **not** $2R$), we have $\|y(t+\delta)-y(t)\| \le L \delta$ and
$y(t+\delta) \in \overline{B}(0,2R)$ as long as $\delta < \min(d-t,{R \over L})$.

In particular, we cannot have $y(t) \in \overline{B}(0,R)$ for any $t>d-{R \over 2L}$
as this would imply that $y(s) \in \overline{B}(0,2R)$ for all $s \in [t,d)$.

Comment: Thanks, it is the proof of the "blow up of a solution in finite time" ?

Comment: It shows that a bounded maximal solution with $d<b$ cannot exist. So, if it is maximal and $d<b$ it cannot be bounded. (Actually, this on its own does not show that $\|y(t)\| \to \infty$.)